# CSS drop down menu absolute - need clarification

Tags: css

---

Hi

I have this fat menu code from http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/819_megamenu/demo/index.html#:

```
<ul id="main">
<li><a href="" class="drop">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown_2columns"><!-- Begin 2 columns container -->

        <div class="col_2">
            <h2>Welcome !</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col_2">
            <p>Hi and welcome here ! This is a showcase of the possibilities of this awesome Mega Drop Down Menu.</p>             
            <p>This item comes with a large range of prepared typographic stylings such as headings, lists, etc.</p>             
        </div>

        <div class="col_2">
            <h2>Cross Browser Support</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="col_1">
            <img src="img/browsers.png" width="125" height="48" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="col_1">
            <p>This mega menu has been tested in all major browsers.</p>
        </div>

    </div
</li>
```

The relevant portion of the style is:

```
.dropdown_1column, 
.dropdown_2columns, 
.dropdown_3columns, 
.dropdown_4columns,
.dropdown_5columns {
    margin:4px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align:left;
}

.dropdown_1column {width: 140px;}
.dropdown_2columns {width: 280px;}
.dropdown_3columns {width: 420px;}
.dropdown_4columns {width: 560px;}
.dropdown_5columns {width: 700px;}

#menu li:hover .dropdown_1column, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_2columns, 
#menu li:hover .dropdown_3columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_4columns,
#menu li:hover .dropdown_5columns {
    left:-1px;
    top:auto;
}

#menu li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
    margin-top:7px;
    border:none;
}

#menu li:hover {
}

#menu li a {
    display:block;
    outline:0;
}   

    #menu li:hover a {
    color:#161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff;
}
#menu li .drop {
    padding-right:21px;
    background:url("img/drop.png") no-repeat right 8px;
}
```

Even though the position of the dropdown menu is mentioned as absolute - there is no mention of the absolute position (ie co-ordinates). If the position:absolute is removed then, the subsequent elements (such as "5 elements", etc) are floated around the dropdown menu (ie the one that pops up after selecting the "Home" menu from menubar). Hence absolute is making the drop down to be placed directly under the home in the menubar and the next menu "5 columns" is placed next to "home" in the menu bar and not next to the dropdown menu. Then how is this working (ie how is the browser understanding it to be rendered as absolute) without mentioning the values of top/bottom/left/right co-ordinates? In other examples of position: absolute such as for the ones in w3schools, the position is mentioned directly ie top: 10px, left: 5px etc. But here that is happening like magic (but is not helping my understanding at all). So please help me understand this and would highly appreciate such help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a child element is `position:absolute` and the parent is `position:relative`, then the child inherits the positioning of the parent. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/CdBHQ/

One reason why the parent might be `relative` of the example you posted is because you will want the dropdowns to move with the navigation bar. Hardcoding in positions would require you to hardcode them again for every change of position.

In your example, each column is given a width. When you however, its starting position is inherited from the `relative` parent, and then naturally flows to the right.